# Does using Ruby's 'push' method cause the value to be dropped from the original array?

Tags: ruby, methods

I found the following code as a solution to a beginner Ruby problem involving randomization.  I realize Ruby has a `shuffle` method, however the purpose of my question is specifically about `push`.

```
def shuffle arr
    shuf = []
    while arr.length > 0

        # Randomly pick one element of the array.
        rand_index = rand(arr.length)

        # Now go through each item in the array,
        # putting them all into new_arr except for the # randomly chosen one, which goes into shuf. 

        curr_index = 0
        new_arr = []
        arr.each do |item|
            if curr_index == rand_index
                shuf.push item
            else
                new_arr.push item
            end

            curr_index = curr_index + 1
        end

        # Replace the original array with the new, # smaller array.
        puts arr.inspect
        arr = new_arr
    end
    shuf
end

shuffle_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
shuffle(shuffle_array)
```

The output at the command line was:

```
Rick:programs rickthomas$ ruby shuffleSolution.rb
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 9]
[1, 3, 4, 9]
[3, 4, 9]
[3, 9]
[3]
Rick:programs rickthomas$
```

Judging by the `while arr.length > 0` line, it appears that `arr` decreases incrementally, which I assume is due to `pushing` items from `arr` to either of the other two arrays.  To test this assumption, I've been messing around with the following code:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
array2 = []
array3 = []
array1.each do |x|
  random_num = rand(2)
  if random_num == 1
    array2.push x
  else
    array3.push x
  end
  puts array1.inspect

end
```

I expected array1 to decrease in a similar way to the `shuffle` method above, but instead I got this:

```
Rick:programs rickthomas$ ruby socratesWork.rb
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Rick:programs rickthomas$
```

Why does `push` remove array items in the first snippet, but not in the second one?  Am I just missing a syntax error somewhere, or am I misunderstanding something more fundamental about `push`?

I searched Stack Overflow already for the answer to this question, and couldn't find a similar question posted yet.  I also checked out ruby-doc.org, but it only talked about adding to an array, not moving (?) items from one array to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are pushing all elements **except the one with the matching index** to `new_arr`. Its size is decreasing by one in every iteration.

Comment: Got it- and then since I'm replacing the old array with the new array, of course 'arr' would be one shorter.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you replace your array by a smaller array at each iteration.

```
 # Replace the original array with the new, # smaller array.
    puts arr.inspect
    arr = new_arr
```

Comment: @Intrepidd- Right, but why is new_arr one item smaller in length than the original array?

Comment: Look at this piece of code :

    ``if curr_index == rand_index
      shuf.push item
    else
      new_arr.push item
    end``

The new_arr will have all the elements of arr except one random for each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

In your first snippet, the inner loop splits the original array `arr` into 2 part:

1. The element which matches the random index, and it is pushed into the array `shuf`
2. Those elements which don't match the random index, they were pushed in to `new_arr`, which is initialized as empty array in each outer loop.

So in each outer loop, `shuf` gets one more element, and `new_arr` receives all the elements in `arr` excepted the randomly chosen one. The ***MAGIC*** comes out at the last line of the outer loop, where `new_arr` is assigned to `arr`. So every loop `arr` becomes one element smaller. That's not the magic or side effect of `Array#push`.

Comment: Got it, since I'm not replacing the old array with the new (smaller) array in the 2nd snippet, of course it will stay the same length.  Thanks for that.